# Can defendant respond to a summons via e-mail?

Tags: litigation

The plaintiff served a defendant with a summons to pay debt.

The defendant filed a written response with the clerk of court in person, but must also send a copy to the plaintiff via mail or in person.

Can the defendant send the copy of the response via e-mail?

Comment: Where?  The law can be (and often is) different in each of London, Ontario; London, Ohio; London, Arkansas; London, Kentucky; and London, England.

Comment: Where can I find the law relevant to the state? @MartinBonner